# Error : Number of Rows In Section in UITableView in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I am getting this error while I am trying to load the data into my table view.

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (73) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (71), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (3 inserted, 0 deleted).`

What could be wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT** :

I am initializing the array on ViewWillAppear and adding new objects to the same array on Tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

**Here is the code On viewWillAppear :**

```
     cellTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[cellTextArray addObjectsFromArray:newPosts];
```

**Here is the code which modifies the array on didSelectRowAtIndexPath :**

```
       [cellTextArray addObjectsFromArray:newPosts];

       NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSUInteger item = count; item < count + newCount; item++) {

            [insertIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:item 
                                                           inSection:0]];
        }

        [self.table beginUpdates];
        [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths 
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.table endUpdates];

        [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone 
                                      animated:YES];

        NSIndexPath *selected = [self.table indexPathForSelectedRow];
        if (selected) {
            [self.table deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected animated:YES];
        }
```

Here **newPosts** is an array which has the values that are added to **cellTextArray** on
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and viewWillAppear method.

Comment: add your code to get the answer! no one can assume and answer to your question.

Comment: @Manjunath: I have edited my question and added the code. Please check it out

Comment: Add [self.table reloadData]; line at the end of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @Satya: I tried [self.table reloadData] but it doesn't seem to help. What can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is with the statement in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

You have added the following statement

```
[self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This statement adds the new rows to the table. but the number of rows in the datasource array for that section is different with the number of rows in that section of that table.

So the App is terminated.

Please try by removing the above statement and add required data to the dataSource Array at required indexes and reload the table

Regards,

Satya

Comment: Thanks for your help @gypsicoder:Thanks as your comment about commenting out beginUpdates and endUpdates portion did help. Thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have updated the array of data after initialization then you can call this method [yourTable reloadData].

And, it be better if you post the codes here. Then may be some one can help you quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have edited my question and added the code. Please check it out. Also where should I put the [table reloadData] statement in my code?

Comment: will you please try by commenting these 2 lines [self.table beginUpdates]; and [self.table endUpdates];

Comment: I tried commenting out the two lines you have mentioned above but doesn't seem to help. what could be wrong?